# Implementing notes option in website

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I would like to implement/embed a notes area where people can write some notes on my website.
is this possible with some simple html script? And if yes, does someone know where to find?

Here you can see what I mean: http://bwmbroadcast.org/player/flash?stream=MP4BW489-3A.mp4

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are these notes visible only to the author? or are they publicly visible like comments?

Comment: It's just as it is on that site. Just for the person who makes the notes. It don't need to be stored. Only a print option.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks bazmegakapa. Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this by simply using HTML+CSS.

You have several options:

- Use a simple HTML form that submits data to the server and save the notes to a database (you can use PHP and MySQL for this). Form submission can happen through AJAX. This seems to be the right way to me.
- Use Javascript and save the notes in a cookie (this way you do not tie it to a user but a browser, I don't recommend this)
- Use benhowdle89's solution, you need Javascript for that too, and HTML5 local storage support is not in every browser right now (still, notes will be tied to the browser, so if I visit your site from a different computer/browser, I won't be able to access them).

UPDATE: If you don't want to store notes at all, and only want it for printing, you could check out `contenteditable`. No need for Javascript here. See: http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Answer (score 4):

If i were you i would implement a HTML-5 local storage system, http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/building-persistant-sticky-notes-with-local-storage/

Comment: you could achieve something quite similar with just cookies w/o the need for HTML5

Comment: yeah i know, its just that tutorial sprang to mind when the O/P asked about Notes...

Comment: Looks very nice! But it's a little too much. Isn't there an easyer way without using javascript?

Comment: bazmegakapa gave you some options, i cant really think of any better ways to do it. Do you mean like "Post It Stickies" in Windows Vista/7 so people can make quick notes?

Comment: You could just have a div with a class of "printable" and when the user types into a textarea, take the .val() of the textarea and use .replaceWith(), a bit like Stack Overflows Ask Question features.

Comment: @benhowdle89 This will also be a fine solution. Thanks.